# Crystal report Runtime for vs2010 in win10 with IE11 silverlight application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, web-applications, internet-explorer-11, crystal-reports-2010

I have Silverlight application with
Crystal report 10
After publish the site and host in iis
In win7 with IE8 report run fine
But in win10 with IE11 report not opened 
Please can anyone help? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Silverlight version, from [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight), we can see that, the Silverlight 5 version works well in Win7 and Win10 systems.

Besides, about the Crystal report, please refer to the following thread and check whether the ActiveX filtering is turned on and try to add the site of crystal report into IE compatibility view:

[crystal report viewer do not show in internet explorer 11](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1da0a049-8514-4274-a70f-1cf2f127c4bf/crystal-report-viewer-do-not-show-in-internet-explorer-11?forum=ieitprocurrentver)

[Crystal Report ActiveX Viewer unable to run in Internet Explorer 11](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/756c56a6-0dee-4b46-bf6d-1a7f618148bc/crystal-report-activex-viewer-unable-to-run-in-internet-explorer-11?forum=ieitprocurrentver)

Comment: Thank you so much , it's silverlight 4